# How to debounce elm signals?

Tags: elm

Im using `start-app` to shape my application. `Html.Events` supports creating custom events with custom `Signal.message`. But how to send that message is abstracted behind the Html library. Also there is a library called which implements debouncing (http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/Signal-Time#settledAfter).

SearchBar.elm:

```
module PhotosApp.SearchBar (view) where

import Html exposing (input, div, button, text, Html)
import Html.Events exposing (on, onClick, targetValue)
import Html.Attributes exposing (value, type')

import Effects exposing (Effects, Never)

import PhotosApp.Actions as Actions

onTextChange : Signal.Address a -> (String -> a) -> Html.Attribute
onTextChange address contentToValue =
    on "input" targetValue (\str -> Signal.message address (contentToValue str))

view : Signal.Address Actions.Action -> String -> Html
view address model =
    div []
        [ input  [ type' "text", value model, onTextChange address Actions.Search] []
        , button [ onClick address Actions.Clear ] [text "Clear"]
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up debouncing from an HTML attribute by going through a proxy mailbox before tying into @Apanatshka's `settledAfter` function.

*(Note that since you're using StartApp, we don't have direct access to the main Address and therefore I've had to compromise a few of these functions by ignoring the `address` passed into `view`. You could get something more generalized by not using StartApp, but this should hopefully get you started)*

Since event attributes cannot create tasks directly, we have to use an intermediate proxy mailbox. We can set that up like this:

```elm
debounceProxy : Signal.Mailbox Action
debounceProxy =
  Signal.mailbox NoOp
```

Note that the above function expects a `NoOp` Action, common in Elm architecture, which just means the `update` function makes no changes to the model.

Now we need to set up another Signal which listens to the proxy mailbox, then passes the signal through the `settledAfter` function. We can define this signal like this:

```elm
debounce : Signal Action
debounce =
  settledAfter (500 * Time.millisecond) debounceProxy.signal
```

We can now change the `onTextChange` function to point at the proxy mailbox. Notice that I've taken out the first `Address` parameter since it's being ignored (see my earlier comment about conforming to StartApp):

```elm
onTextChange : (String -> Action) -> Html.Attribute
onTextChange contentToValue =
    on "input" targetValue (\str -> Signal.message debounceProxy.address (contentToValue str))
```

Lastly, you have to tie in the `debounce` signal into StartApp's `inputs` parameter, which means your call to `start` will look something like this:

```elm
app = StartApp.start
  { init = init
  , update = update
  , view = view
  , inputs = [ debounce ]
  }
```

I've pasted the full working example at a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/b49ccf8c2e87d8818fdd).

Comment: Thanks for start-app integration :) Is it possible to define debounce timout in lower level instead of higher level debounce function?

Comment: You can pass in a `Time` parameter to `debounce` like this: `debounce interval = settledAfter interval debounceProxy.signal`, then you would set it in StartApp like this: `inputs = [ debounce (500 * Time.millisecond) ]`

Comment: Yes but still its defined at the higher level. So it seems complicated to give different debounce values for different inputs.

Comment: You don't actually need to define a `debounce` function at the top level. You could instead just pass the signal mapping functions into `inputs`, like this: `inputs = [ settledAfter (500 * Time.millisecond) debounceProxy.signal, settledAfter (1000 * Time.millisecond) debounceProxy2.signal ]`

Comment: Yes of course but still inputs are top level configuration things.

Comment: Oh what i was thinking! Of course i can define each input signal in its own component/module and then collect them where parent component defined until up to application level. Now i got it :D thanks